# Google translation API keeps rejecting request from my server even though it is whitelisted

Tags: google-translate

So basically, I'm trying to translate my magento catalog using google translate api. I've set everything up and whitelisted my app within the project in google cloud platform for the translation API.

Everytime I try to translate, I get this error:

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API
>   key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if
>   request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

Any idea where can I find which IP the the request coming from into my project in google developer console? I see some logs there but I see no ip.

I am pretty sure what my server IP is and I have whitelisted it. When I remove the IP restriction, it works flawlessly1